# Problem after last update

Tags: command-line, nvidia

I am having a problem after the last update, the booting to command line problem

I even can't start in the graphic fail system "xfail":

```
X: cannot stat /etc/X11/X (no such file or directory), aborting
```

I found some one mentioning a solution which is installing ubuntu-dektop though apt-get but it failed due to this error:

```
Unmet dependencies " the dependencies are xserver-xorg-video-all and xserver-xorg-input"
```

Tried to install these first also another dependencies problem.

Solutions I tried:

- removing and installing nvidia driver
- removing and installing xserver
- Tried different versions of nvidia including the latest one which is the one I had before the update

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 Maveric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have partially installed updates you can complete those with `dpkg --configure -a`

You can fix broken dependencies with `apt-get --fix-broken install`

At that point you should be able to fully install X.

Comment: I'll try that now and get back to you

Comment: Shapr you are the best man I have been struggling for days

Just for further information what I did is thus 

I solved the dependencies using shapr post then removed nvidia and xserver installed new fresh ones installed ubuntu-desktop then start gdm service all good now 

Commands used 

'nvidia-uninstall' to remove invidia
'apt-get install ubuntu-desktop' to install ubuntu desktop
'service gdm start' to start gdm 

note that the nvidia driver I installed is the latest for my graphic card from nvidia website using sh command

Comment: Shapr i als ran into the same problem and your answer solved my issue as well thank you

Comment: If you like the solution, vote it up!